# Why do I get an error while trying to install axios?

Tags: javascript, npm, axios

I am trying to install axios to use on my project via this command:

```
npm install axios
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...devDependencies":{"co'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kelvin/.npm/_logs/2021-03-10T05_51_34_276Z-debug.log
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you share your **package.json** file?

Comment: Just check package.json for valid JSON syntax, you can use online tools or if you have an IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first :

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then

```
npm install axios
```